# Finding angle of line w.r.t to origin

Tags: c++, math, geometry, gdi+

I have two points p1 and p2.I want to calculate angle of these vector w.r.t to origin
so I use atan(p1.y-p2.y,p1.x-p2.x)
Now when I calculate as p1(45,45) and p2(200,200) I get answer as 45
and when I use p1(200,200) and p2(45,45) I get answer as 235.
The problem is related to direction to vector.How can I solve the problem?

I have modified the code so that range of atan is in[0,360]

`double factor1=atan2(point2.Y-point1.Y,point2.X-point1.X);
 factor1=(factor1 > 0 ? factor1 : (2*3.1415 + factor1)) * 360 / (2*3.1415);`

I want to draw an arc.So i need a start angle.for the given line.The start angle is the angle made by line in clockwise direction wrt to postive x axis

Comment: It depends on your coordinate system. Does X increase to the left or the right? Do Y increase up or down? Or is the X and Y axles switched, so Y e.g. increase to the left?

Comment: It can be any changes.I get input from a frame where the line values can be in any cordinate

Comment: Please post the code you are using to compute the angle.

Comment: What is "the angle of these vector w.r.t. to origin"? You mean two angles, one for p1 and one for p2, each with respect to the origin of the coordinate system? Or what exactly?

Comment: angle of the line with respect to origin.Because as i have mentioned above when the points get interchanged angle .presently the angle is calculated wrt to positive x axis

Comment: What exactly is the problem with the answers `45` and `235`?  What answers do you expect?

Comment: I always expect 45.same answer.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the difference between your answers (45 and 235) is just the direction they point. Could you subtract 180 from your answer if it is greater than 180?

Comment: the angle value lies in the range of [0,360]

Comment: You need to think about this properly. If you go from p1 to p2 in a certain angle, then you cannot possibly go back from p2 to p1 in the same angle: If you head out from some point p1 in, say, North-Eastern direction and reach p2 after half an hour, and then you head out from p2 in _the same direction_, still North-Eastern, you certainly won't come back to p1. If you want to go back to p1, you need to reverse direction, and that is necessarily reflected by the angle you take.

Comment: I guess what you really mean is that you draw a horizontal line through p1 as well as through p2, and you are interested in the *smallest* angle between the line connecting p1 and p2, and that horizontal line. That is best achieved by subtracting 180 as suggested by Crummy. Make a drawing and think about it.

Comment: The answer you get cannot be 235 !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem.

The direction of the vector (155, 155) is 45°.

The direction of the vector (-155, -155) is the supplement, 45°+180°=225°, or equivalently 45°-180°=-135°.